# Cannot create a list with list in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to create a list with inner lists with following command but it is not working:

> (list 1 2 3 (list a b c))

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable B has no value

I am not sure which is variable B here.

Edit: I restarted clisp and tried again. This time it is variable A!

```
$ clisp 
  i i i i i i i       ooooo    o        ooooooo   ooooo   ooooo
  I I I I I I I      8     8   8           8     8     o  8    8
  I  \ `+' /  I      8         8           8     8        8    8
   \  `-+-'  /       8         8           8      ooooo   8oooo
    `-__|__-'        8         8           8           8  8
        |            8     o   8           8     o     8  8
  ------+------       ooooo    8oooooo  ooo8ooo   ooooo   8

Welcome to GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07) <http://clisp.cons.org/>

Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Michael Stoll 1992, 1993
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Marcus Daniels 1994-1997
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Pierpaolo Bernardi, Sam Steingold 1998
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Sam Steingold 1999-2000
Copyright (c) Sam Steingold, Bruno Haible 2001-2010

Type :h and hit Enter for context help.

[1]> (list 1 2 3 (list a b c))

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable A has no value
The following restarts are available:
```

I tried to set values of variables a, b, c, but still it does not work.

```
[5]> (let ((a 1)(b 2)(c 3)))
NIL
[6]> (list 1 2 3 (list a b c))

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable A has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of A.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for A.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
Break 1 [7]>
```

Comment: Why don't you take a Lisp introduction, like I proposed earlier, instead of randomly experimenting?

Comment: A tip for debugging weird things like this: try it with simpler things first. If `(list 1 2 3 (list a b c))` gives you problems - try `(list 1 2 3)` or `(list a b c)` first. If something simpler works then build up to the complicated expression. if what you did to set variables didn't seem to work, learn more about setting variables (since it didn't seem to work)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the variables before you can use them.

```
(defvar a 10)
(defvar b 20)
(defvar c 30)
(list 1 2 3 (list a b c))
```

This should return:

```
(1 2 3 (10 20 30))
```

When you use `LET`, it creates *local* variables, and their scope is just the body of the `LET`.

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
  (list 1 2 3 (list a b c)))
=> (1 2 3 (1 2 3))
```

Comment: Actually I was using this comand only and it is not working- see my edited question above. I also tried with changed parenthesis and posted that here by mistake.

Comment: Have you set the variables `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: No. That must be the reason.

Comment: `LET` is for creating local variables, not global variables.

Comment: I get most of it now. Thanks.